How to make a sigv4 (Amazon signature) in react
I need to make an api request with sigv4 but I see no way to do it in react. The SDK is old and the docs suggest to use amplify which apparently doesn’t have any way of making the signature.
The available libraries are for node use.
The process of making this from scratch is quite complex and I’m finding it strange that aws doesn’t provide a way of doing this from react.
How to solve this?

Why do the existing Javascript libraries not work for you?

Mostly stuff like this... Everything uses @aws-sdk on the background: node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-process/dist-es/resolveProcessCredentials.js:2:9: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/node-stdlib-browser/esm/mock/empty.js" for import "exec"
node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-sso/dist-es/resolveSSOCredentials.js:3:9: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/@smithy/shared-ini-file-loader/dist-es/index.js" for import "getSSOTokenFromFile"

Making the signature in react (which is intended to be used on the client side) means you will have to expose AWS secrets to the world. The solution is to use the AWS SDK in nodejs (which runs serverside) and run node as a proxy to whatever AWS services you need to access in react.

I found a solution that works as intended at:
https://github.com/mhart/aws4fetch
